# How can I perform a raw query in doctrine mongodb

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

Is there a way to perform a raw query (just as you can do with MySQL) in Doctrine with MongoDB?
I'm trying to do this:

```
db.report.aggregate([{"$group" : {_id:"$content", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

It doesn't seem to be a native aggregate function in Doctrine either, is it?

Answer (score 4):

Following did the trick for me

```
    $dbName = $this->container->getParameter('mongo_db_name');

    $connection = $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getConnection();
    $mongo = $connection->getMongo();
    $db = $mongo->selectDB($dbName);

    $results = $db ->command([
        'aggregate' => 'report',
        'pipeline' => [
            ['$group' => ['_id' => '$content', 'count' => ['$sum' => 1]]]
        ]
    ]);

    return $results;
```

Not sure about native Doctrine function, but in case of aggregations I'd prefer to have RAW JSON output, because it's mostly used to render out some charts.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use an advanced version of a $lookup stage, but sadly, didn't because its **lookup()** method adds just a basic version of a stage like:

```
public  function getExpression(): array
{
    return [
        '$lookup' => [
            'from' => $this->from,
            'localField' => $this->localField,
            'foreignField' => $this->foreignField,
            'as' => $this->as,
        ],
    ];
}
```

An obvious solution would be to provide a custom version of Stage/Lookup.php class, but I didn't want to create a separate file for such a small thing, so I decided to go with inline class:

```
    $lookupExpr = [
        '$lookup' => [...],
    ];

    $aggregationBuilder->addStage(new class($lookupExpr, $aggregationBuilder) extends Aggregation\Stage {
        public function __construct(private array $lookupExpr, Builder $builder) {parent::__construct($builder);}

        public function getExpression(): array
        {
            return $this->lookupExpr;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Doctrine ODM 2.0, the underlying connection is handled by the [mongodb/mongodb package](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) instead of doctrine/mongodb. As such, you can get the connection though doctrine ManagerRegistry::getConnection(), [then use the command function using the mongodb library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/commands/):

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\ManagerRegistry;
class Test {
    function execute(ManagerRegistry $mr) {
        $database= $mr->getConnection()->db_name;

        $cursor = $database->command([
            'geoNear' => 'restos',
            'near' => [
                'type' => 'Point',
                'coordinates' => [-74.0, 40.0],
            ],
            'spherical' => 'true',
            'num' => 3,
        ]);

        $results = $cursor->toArray()[0];

        var_dump($results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use aggregation

```
        $db = $mongo->selectDB('ostrov_sync');
        $dbTable = $mongo->selectCollection($db, 'sync_task');
        $results = $dbTable->aggregate([
            [
                '$match' => [
                    'payloadHash' => [
                        '$eq' => '0000cfdc-c8cf-11e9-9485-000c29d1ed7a',
                    ],
                ],
            ]
         ]);

    dump(results);
```